# Find slope for each observation

Tags: sas

I'm a newbie in SAS. I have a data set with 3 set of lung function measurements for 3 corresponding dates given below for each observation. I would like to extract slope for each observation(decline in lung function) using SAS software  and insert in the new column for each observation.
1. How should I approach the problem?
2. Is my data set arranged in right format?

```
ID      FEV1_Date11 FEV1_Date12 FEV1_Date13  DATE11     DATE12     DATE13
18105   1.35        1.25        1.04         6/9/1990   8/16/1991  8/27/1993
18200   0.87        0.85                     9/12/1991  3/11/1993   
18303   0.79                                 4/23/1992      
24204   4.05        3.95        3.99         6/8/1992   3/22/1993  11/5/1994
28102   1.19        1.04        0.96         10/31/1990 7/24/1991  6/27/1992
34104   1.03        1.16        1.15         7/25/1992  12/8/1993  12/7/1994
43108   0.92        0.83        0.79         6/23/1993  1/12/1994  1/11/1995
103114  2.43        2.28        2.16         6/5/1994   6/21/1995  4/7/1996
114101  0.73        0.59        0.6          6/25/1989  8/5/1990   8/24/1991
```

example for 1st observation, slope=0.0003
[image]
Thanks..

Comment: It's easier if your data is in a long format versus a wide format. If you really want a wide format you can adjust the code here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Forecasting-and-Econometrics/Regression-type-problem-data-in-a-row/m-p/276735/

Comment: your first row has y values as 1.35,1.25 and 1.04.  Are you sure you want the difference between your x values to represent the number of days between dates?